How do I organize my binary parser's code?
I'm building a Mach-O 64 bit binary parser for a reverse engineering tool, ghidra style.
I want the program to output where we are in readable human language, only using file format identifiers.
Let me show you an example:
0x100000004: cf fa ed fe
0x100000008: 0c 00 00 01
0x10000000c: 00 00 00 00
0x100000010: 02 00 00 00
0x100000014: 11 00 00 00
0x100000018: 20 04 00 00
0x10000001c: 85 00 20 00
0x100000020: 00 00 00 00
0x100000024: 19 00 00 00 LC_SEGMENT_64

Here, LC_SEGMENT_64 is on the side of the where it starts, i know this because the LC_SEGMENT_64 identifier is 0x19. But if i do this to every single possible Mach-O identifier it's going to get messy. How do I implement this in a good way, without using 50 thousand if-else statements?
My code atm:
#include <errno.h>
#include <mach-o/loader.h>
#include <mach/machine.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4
#define ERROR(msg) fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s | %s\n", msg, strerror(errno));

void HexPrinter(uint32_t buffer, FILE *binary) {
  uint64_t mem_addr = 0x10000000;
  fread(&buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, binary);
  if (buffer != MH_MAGIC_64) {
    ERROR("Not a 64-bit Mach-O binary");
    return;
  } else {
    printf("0x%llx: %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", mem_addr, (buffer & 0xFF),
           ((buffer >> 9) & 0xFF), ((buffer >> 16) & 0xFF),
           ((buffer >> 24) & 0xFF));
  }

  while ((fread(&buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, binary)) == BUFFER_SIZE) {
    printf("0x%llx: %02x %02x %02x %02x\t", mem_addr, (buffer & 0xFF),
           ((buffer >> 9) & 0xFF), ((buffer >> 16) & 0xFF),
           ((buffer >> 24) & 0xFF));

/* I don't want to write one of these for each identifier */
    if (buffer == LC_SEGMENT_64) {
      printf("LC_SEGMENT_64\n");
    } else {
      printf("\n");
    }

    mem_addr += BUFFER_SIZE;
  }

  if (ferror(binary)) {
    ERROR("Error reading file");
    fclose(binary);
    return;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[1]) {
  FILE *binary;
  char *pathname = argv[1];

  uint32_t buffer;

  if (!argv[1]) {
    ERROR("Usage: ./nibBrev <pathname>");
    return (-1);
  }

  binary = fopen(pathname, "r");
  if (!binary) {
    ERROR("Couldn't open file");
    return (-1);
  }

  HexPrinter(buffer, binary);

  fclose(binary);
  return 0;
}


Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Is sounds like your question is about formatting and not how to parse the binary into a relevant context. Please provide the code you've written so far.

I read the loader.h file provided from this question for the Mach-O format you are working with and will target my answer to what I read there. If this link is out of date or not correct adjust based on what you are working with.
The constants you mention are sequential starting at #define LC_SEGMENT 0x1 and ending at #define LC_BUILD_VERSION 0x32. Create a mapping from these constants to indices in a table of strings like this.
/* This is how many identifiers I saw listed in loader.h add one 
   for the 0th unused slot. Number based on the last identifier in
   the list of constants or count by hand. Either works. */
#define NUM_IDENTIFIERS LC_BUILD_VERSION + 1
static const char *const identifier_strings[NUM_IDENTIFIERS] = {
    /* Probably unused 0th slot. */
    [0] = "",
    [LC_SEGMENT] = "LC_SEGMENT",
    [LC_SYMTAB] = "LC_SYMTAB",
    /* ...continues for rest of identifier constants */

    /* careful with constants OR'd with LC_REQ_DYLD bit.
       Or do this to all values to be safe, maybe? */
    [LC_RPATH & ~LC_REQ_DYLD] = "LC_RPATH",

    /* ...continues */
    [LC_BUILD_VERSION] = "LC_BUILD_VERSION",
};

The strings are now always in sync with those constants and the string table can be reorganized in any way for readability because of the [index] = "string", notation used.
Now a lookup function might look like this.
const char *lookup(uint32_t identifier) {
    /* While the identifiers are sequential be mindful of
       the LC_REQ_DYLD bit that has been OR'd to some in
       the list. That would mess up the indexing. See the
       comment above this constant for more info. */
    identifier &= ~LC_REQ_DYLD;
    if (identifier && identifier < NUM_IDENTIFIERS) {
        return identifier_strings[identifier];
    }
    return NULL;
}

Then same as the other answer.
const char *id = lookup(buffer);
if (id) {
    puts(id);
} else {
    puts('\n');
}

Warning: I assume you are only interested in the LC_* section of identifiers. Both Ted Lyngmo's answer and mine would not work if you added more constants to print from loader.h because I see the same values used for many different #defines throughout the file.

Nice catch with the multiple values. I guess one could map to an array of strings to cover that.

Yes, i was only interested in the LC_* section. I managed to make a solution based on yours, thank you!

You could make a map that maps from identifier to string with the help of bsearch:
#include <stdlib.h>  // for bsearch - binary search

// a struct to hold the value and string for _one_ identifier
typedef struct {
    uint32_t val;
    char const *str;
} identifier;

// all your identifiers goes here, in ascending order
const identifier identifiers[] = {
    {LC_SEGMENT_64, "LC_SEGMENT_64"},
    {SOMETHING_ELSE, "SOMETHING_ELSE"},
};

// comparison function for bsearch
int compare(const void *lhs, const void *rhs) {
    const identifier *lid = lhs;
    const identifier *rid = rhs;
    if (lid->val < rid->val) return -1;
    if (lid->val > rid->val) return 1;
    return 0;
}

// a function to encapsulate the call to bsearch
const char *lookup(uint32_t id) {
    identifier key = {id, NULL};
    identifier *res = bsearch(&key,
                              identifiers,
                              sizeof identifiers / sizeof key,
                              sizeof key,
                              compare);
    if(res) return res->str;
    return NULL;
}

Then instead of
if (buffer == LC_SEGMENT_64) {
      printf("LC_SEGMENT_64\n");
} else if (buffer == SOMETHING_ELSE) {
      printf("SOMETHING_ELSE\n");
} else if (buffer == ...) {
      printf("...\n");
} else {
      printf("\n");
}

You would only need one if:
const char *id = lookup(buffer);
if (id) {
    puts(id);
} else {
    putchar('\n');
}

Demo
